# Can't seem to get dynamic filesystem based routing to work with Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs, dynamic-routing

Imagine the following endpoints:

```
/categories/{id}
/categories/{id}/sub-categories/{sub-id}
```

The file system structure would be:

```
categories
    sub-categories
        _subId.vue
    _id.vue
```

Now the expectation is that if I hit:

```
/categories/1
```

It would load `_id.vue` and that works fine. However, if I hit:

```
/categories/1/sub-categories/25
```

It still loads `_id.vue`. `_subId` never seems to load.

What is cuasing this issue?

<sub>I would include the code, but strictly speaking, it doesn't seem necessary, if it's required, do ask.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

It should be structured:

```
categories
    _id
        sub-categories
            _subId.vue
        index.vue
```

**Further Reading**

[Dyanmic nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing/#dynamic-nested-routes)